# In-app chat would be nice

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app

I'm open to pitching in with the code.

The seams between chat and main are bothersome to me.

Comment: SE chat isn't open source - and development is frozen on it. And chat's... not really a top priority. I totally don't see this happening any time soon. Would be amusing if someone built a better SE android/iphone client with chat tho.